# Best practice for changing TextBox Border color?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

Suppose you have a View with multiple Texboxes like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myText1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

each already containing some text. If the user changes this text the Textbox Border should change to Orange and if he undos his changes it should get it's default color.

At the moment I do it like this

```
<TextBox Height="23"  Text="{Binding myText1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" BorderThickness="2">
   <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding myDirtyText1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Is there a more generic / simpler way to do this?

**Edit**

I am already using `IDataErrorInfo` + `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` for Error validation. Maybe there is a similar way in this case but I didn't found anything useful to reduce my xaml and code to an minimum.

## EDIT 2.0

i think you doesn't really understand my problem so i will provide a better sample of how it actual looks like:

### View Xaml (no codebehind)

```
<Grid Margin="12">
    <Label Content="Name:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" BorderThickness="2"
             Text="{Binding NameD, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding dirtyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="Anzeigetext:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
    <TextBox BorderThickness="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
             Text="{Binding AnzeigetextD, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding dirtyAnzeigetext, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="Preis:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
    <TextBox BorderThickness="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
             Text="{Binding PreisD, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat=\{0:c\}}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding dirtyPreis, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>

    <Button Content="Speichern" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Abbrechen" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="197,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

### ViewModel

```
public class MenuangebotVM : DetailVM, IContains
{
    #region private Values
    private Menuangebot myOriginal = new Menuangebot();
    private Menuangebot myValue = new Menuangebot();
    #endregion // private Values

    #region Properties

    #region Detail Properties
    public int Id { get { return myOriginal.Id; } }
    public bool? Result { get; private set; }
    public string Beschreibung { get { return "Einrichtung"; } }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜß''-'\s]{2,40}$")]
    public string NameD
    {
        get { return myValue.Name; }
        set
        {
            myValue.Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => NameD));
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => dirtyName));
        }
    }
    public bool dirtyName
    {
        get { return (!isNew && myValue.Name != myOriginal.Name) ? true : false; }
    }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜß''-'\s]{2,25}$")]
    public string AnzeigetextD
    {
        get { return myValue.Anzeigetext; }
        set
        {
            myValue.Anzeigetext = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => AnzeigetextD));
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => dirtyAnzeigetext));
        }
    }
    public bool dirtyAnzeigetext
    {
        get { return (!isNew && myValue.Anzeigetext != myOriginal.Anzeigetext) ? true : false; }
    }

    [Required]
    public decimal PreisD
    {
        get { return myValue.Preis; }
        set
        {
            myValue.Preis = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => PreisD));
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => dirtyPreis));
        }
    }
    public bool dirtyPreis
    {
        get
        {
            var value = myValue.Preis;
            var Original = myOriginal.Preis;

            return (!isNew && value != Original) ? true : false;
        }
    }

    #endregion //Detail Properties
    #endregion //Properties

// more code

}
```

## what i excspect should be something like

### View

```
<Grid Margin="12">
    <Label Content="Name:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" BorderThickness="2"
             Text="{Binding NameD, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, EditesOnDataChanges=true}">

    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="Anzeigetext:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
    <TextBox BorderThickness="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
             Text="{Binding AnzeigetextD, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, EditesOnDataChanges=true}">
    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="Preis:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
    <TextBox BorderThickness="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" 
             Text="{Binding PreisD, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, StringFormat=\{0:c\, EditesOnDataChanges=true}}">
    </TextBox>

    <Button Content="Speichern" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    <Button Content="Abbrechen" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="197,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

### ViewModel

```
public class MenuangebotVM : DetailVM, IContains
{
    #region private Values
    private Menuangebot myOriginal = new Menuangebot();
    private Menuangebot myValue = new Menuangebot();
    #endregion // private Values

    #region Properties

    #region Detail Properties
    public int Id { get { return myOriginal.Id; } }
    public bool? Result { get; private set; }
    public string Beschreibung { get { return "Einrichtung"; } }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜß''-'\s]{2,40}$")]
    [Default(myOriginal.Name)] //<-- added
    public string NameD
    {
        get { return myValue.Name; }
        set
        {
            myValue.Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => NameD));
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜß''-'\s]{2,25}$")]
    [Default(myOriginal.Anzeigetext)] //<-- added
    public string AnzeigetextD
    {
        get { return myValue.Anzeigetext; }
        set
        {
            myValue.Anzeigetext = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => AnzeigetextD));
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [Default(myOriginal.Preis)] //<-- added
    public decimal PreisD
    {
        get { return myValue.Preis; }
        set
        {
            myValue.Preis = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => PreisD));
        }
    }    
    #endregion //Detail Properties
    #endregion //Properties

// more code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string initialText;
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Text = "ABCD";
            initialText = Text;
            DefaultBorder = true;
        }
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { text = value;
            if (value == initialText)
                DefaultBorder = true;
            else
                DefaultBorder = false;
                Notify("Text"); }
        }

        private bool defaultBorder;
        public bool DefaultBorder
        {
            get { return defaultBorder; }
            set { defaultBorder = value; Notify("DefaultBorder"); }
        }

        private void Notify(string propertyName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged!=null)
                PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value is bool && !(bool)value)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy); //Or default whatever you want

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    <Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="{Binding DefaultBorder, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Here I have property Text in ViewModel that is bound to TextBox and at the beginning i preserved the initial Text value . and then whenever user type i compare it in setter of Text property and set Bool Property accordingly , this bool property will specify which color to Bind using converter.Ignore minor issues hope you will get an idea.

Comment: mhh so i only move the problem (self repeating) in my Text Property and didn't deny them. I thought there could be a `ValidationAttribute` Solution

Comment: you mean you want to show Orange Border Brush as Error in Text.

Comment: no not as Error just as Visual eye catcher if the actual `Text != startText`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably turn this to a custom control/UserControl and add a IsDirtyDependencyProperty, and the IsDirtyColorDependencyProperty (or attached dependency property). That way you replace all your textboxes with this and not have to repeat the code over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally I just had a problem almost identical to yours, and I solved it by wrapping the `TextBox` in a `Border`. Furthermore, this also solved a problem whereby BorderBrush colours cannot be changed on Windows 8 machines.

I would thus recommend this approach. The code is quite straightforward, whereby you just add your textBox to the `Border` and change the border's `BorderBrush` property.

Comment: so you created a costume Control like TYY suggested?

Comment: @WiiMaxx - No, my approach is a lot simpler than that. Literally just wrap your TextBox inside a `Border` control. No need for any custom controls.

Comment: could you please show me an example because i can't see the improvement in your solution at the moment

Comment: I don't have access to any code at the moment, but you can read about the `Border` control and its properties over here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx

You may notice that the property `Child` is perfect for storing your TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attached behavior for that

```
public static class TextChangedAttachedBehavior
{
    public static bool GetChanged(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ChangedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetChanged(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ChangedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChangedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Changed", typeof(bool),
        typeof(TextChangedAttachedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, HookupBehavior));

    private static void HookupBehavior(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = d as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null) 
            return;
        textBox.TextChanged += TextBoxOnTextChanged;
    }

    private static void TextBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
            return;
        textBox.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }
}
```

And than in xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myText1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" TextChangedAttachedBehavior.Changed = "True" />
```